como obtener resultados de un array en otro array
soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y tengo unas dudas que no consigo aclarar, aver si alguien es capaz de iluminarme un poco sobre como debo de hacerlo...
la primera es que tengo 2 arrays de informacion, que debo de obtener para mandarsela a otro array y que por medio de un foreeach , me cree un fragmento de codigo html, en concreto un elemeto li...
el codigo php es este:
<?php
$imagen = array("model_1.jpg", "model_2.jpg", "model_3.jpg", "model_4.jpg");
$name = array("Ana", "Juan", "Pedro", "Julia");
$models = array(
                array ("href" => "../../Public/img/", $imagen),
                array ("title" => $name)
                );
                  foreach ($models as $model) {
                    echo"<li class='card'>";

la segunda duda es que el elemento li es un poco largo y extenso y por mucho que he buscado por la web , no dado con la respuesta idonea... el tema es que estoy intentado que dicho codigo li en html , se me replique tantas veces , como datos extrae el foreach, es decir en el codigo de arriba debo de obtener 4 nombres y 4 url's, pues que dicho elemento li se me replique 4 veces, sin tener que recurrir al echo""; en cada linea html y generar el codigo 4 veces con lo distintos valores que me da el array....
he probado con la sintaxis heredoc , creando una variable $codigo = $EOT; codigo html EOT; , pero sin exito, alguien podria orientarme, sobre como hacerlo??
el codigo del li , deberia de replicarse , seria este:
foreach ($models as $model) {
                    echo"<li class='card'>"; 
                        echo"<div class='model'>"; 
                            echo"<a data-action='Navegacion' data-track='Imagen' href='#' title='$name'>"; 
                                echo"<picture>";
                                    echo"<img src='../../Public/img/'".$model"' alt='"$name"' class='img-responsive'>"; 
                                echo"</picture>";
                            echo"</a>"; 
                        echo"<div>"; 
                        echo"<h3>"; 
                            echo"<a data-action='Navegacion' data='Nombre' href='#'>$name</a>";
                                echo"<form action="">";
                                    echo"<input class='Url_Foto' type='url' name='Url_Foto' id='Url_Foto' size='20' value='' placeholder=''>";
                                    echo"<input class='Search_File' type='file' name='archivo' id='Search_File' size='10' value='Examinar'>";
                                    echo"<input  name='Name' type='text' id='Name' size='30' value='' placeholder=''>";                                    
                              echo"</form>";  
                           echo"</h3>";  
                           echo"<ul class='details'>";  
                               echo"<li>";  
                                   echo"<a href='#'>";  
                                       echo"<span class='glyphicons glyphicons-play'></span>";  
                                       echo"<strong class='number'>4</strong>";                                       
                   echo"</a>";  
                               echo"</li>"; 
                               echo"<li class='number-likes'>";   
                                   echo"<a href='#";
                                       echo"<span class='glyphicons glyphicons-thumbs-up'></span>";  
                                           echo"<strong>81</strong>";  
                                   echo"</a>";  
                               echo"</li>";  
                          echo"</ul>"; 
                          echo"<ul class='model-category'>";  
                              echo"<li class='model_cat'>";
                                  echo"<a href="#><?php $cat_model ?></a>";
                              echo"</li>"; 
                          echo"</ul>";
                       echo"</div>";   
                            echo"</div>";
                        echo"</li>";
                        }
                       

y como vereis hay mucha linea que replicar, como para hacer con echo"";
hay alguna otra forma???

Puedes escribir una especie de plantilla con marcadores y sustituir los marcadores por variables usando printf. Pero eso no me cuadra. En tu ejemplo aparece un cierre de </form> sin apertura. Se necesita un ejemplo completo de lo que esperas obtener.

gracias por tu respuesta ,el cierre del form si que tiene apertura, solo que al copiar y pegar aqui, se ha quedado mal tabulado, por otro lado , ya habia pensado en hacerlo asi como tu dices  con codigo html'', el problema es que para si lo hago asi , tengo que escribir todos los li y  quiero que los li me los cree php  segun reccorre el arrayt... no se si me explico, por otro lado, el codigo html deberia de estar dentro de las llaves del foreach, si no me equivoco con lo cual llego a mi segunda duda, la forma de escribir mucho codigo html sin tanto 'echo'

En este sitio las preguntas se hacen de una en una para que los demás las encuentren más facilmente, sino es un lio para todos.
Creo que tu planteamiento de arrays no es correcto, pues parece que lo complicas un poco de ese modo.
Creo que lo que tu quieres es usar un único array con esto:
$asignaciones = [
    "Ana" => "model_1.jpg",
    "Juan" => "model_2.jpg",
    "Pedro" => "model_3.jpg",
    "Julia" => "model_4.jpg",
];

para luego hacer el bucle sobre el de este modo:
foreach ($asignaciones as $nombre => $imagen) {

En cuanto a lo del html y los echos, mi método es crear una variable vacia antes del bucle e ir agregando el contenido del bucle en cada pasada, y al final del bucle hacer un único echo de la variable que contendrá todo a la vez.
En cuanto a la sintaxis, te recomiendo que uses el entrecomillado simple para almacenar el contenido html en la variable, y no las comillas dobles, y así puedes usarlas dentro de la variable en HTML y así no hacer cosas raras con el, pues aunque funcione y sea HTML válido, normalmente complica la vida y hace el código menos legible.
Para mostrar los valores de las variables pasadas, usando el entrecomillado simple, se soluciona abriendo y cerrándolo en cada ocasión que lo necesites.
En resumen, seria cambiar algo como esto:
echo "<a href='$variable'>";

por esto:
$salida .= '<a href="'.$variable.'">';

Si tienes un editor de texto que te pinta de colores la sintaxis lo verás mejor que aquí y lo entenderás mejor.
Aquí tienes tu código refactorizado de ese modo que acabo de explicar (ojo que tienes un <a sin cerrar bien, ya lo encontrarás):
<?php
$asignaciones = [
    "Ana" => "model_1.jpg",
    "Juan" => "model_2.jpg",
    "Pedro" => "model_3.jpg",
    "Julia" => "model_4.jpg",
];

$salida = '';  // inicializamos una variable vacia que irá acumulando la salida del bucle
foreach ($asignaciones as $nombre => $imagen) {
    $salida .= '
    <li class="card">
        <div class="model">
            <a data-action="Navegacion" data-track="Imagen" href="#" title="<?php echo $name ?>">
                <picture>
                    <img src="../../Public/img/'.$imagen.'" alt="'.$nombre.'" class="img-responsive">
                </picture>
            </a>
            <div>
                <h3><a data-action="Navegacion" data="Nombre" href="#">'.$nombre.'</a>
                    <form action="">
                        <input class="Url_Foto" type="url" name="Url_Foto" id="Url_Foto" size="20" value="" placeholder="">
                        <input class="Search_File" type="file" name="archivo" id="Search_File" size="10" value="Examinar">
                        <input  name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="30" value="" placeholder="">
                    </form>
                </h3>
                <ul class="details">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-play"></span>
                            <strong class="number">4</strong>  
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="number-likes">
                        <a href="#"
                            <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-thumbs-up"></span>
                            <strong>81</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="model-category">
                    <li class="model_cat">
                        <a href="#'.$cat_model.'</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';
}
echo $salida;

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucha ayuda y ademas he aprendido otra forma de imprimir html en una funcion , sin recurrir nada mas que a un solo 'echo'.... Muchisimas gracias serias un buen profe....

solo una duda mas con este sistema puedo añadir todos los elemetos que quiera al array ???, es decir si en un trabajo model_1 , han trabajado dos alumnos  puedo añadir  ana, juan  y luego añadir una variable mas al foreach '$nombre_1'???

@VP Siempre que los agregues del mismo modo que estan ahora, si, puedes agregar tantos elementos al array como precises, repitiendo los nombres de las imágenes sin problema (entiendo que al menos los nombres son únicos)

Una forma de imprimir elementos largos de html, es usando la estructura foreach(): … endforeach;.
En tu caso seria:
foreach ($models as $model) : 
# Inicio de html
?>
   <li>
   …
   </li>
<?php
# Fin de html
endforeach;

Cuando necesites imprimir una variable de php dentro de html, ej $name, puedes hacer

<a data-action='Navegacion' data='Nombre' href='#'>   
   <!—- Imprime tu variable usando <?= ?> ——>
   <?= $name ?>   
</a>



Diria que tienes un typo (error tipográfico), pues no es <= ?>  sino <?= ?>

gracias por tu respuesta,  el unico problema que veo de hacerlo asi es que tengo que repetir  el codigo html de cada li y escribir todos los li, y lo que quiero es que php recorra el array y me cree un li completo , vuelve a recorrer el array y me genara un nuevo li completo y asi hasta terminar con todas las variables del array

masterguru tienes razón me faltó un signo de pregunta

Si pones el elemento  dentro del foreach como está en la respuesta este se repetirá tantas veces como lo diga el foreach

bueno lo ultimo que he probado , ha sido con la sintaxis heredoc, pero me da error de variables no definidas.... por si alguien sabe como solucionarlo...
$models = array(
            array ("href" => "../../Public/img/"),
            array ("name" => "Matty Mila Perez", "name" => "Cherry Candle", "name" => "Fibi Euro", "name" => "Florane Russell"),
            array ("image" => "model_1.jpg", "imagen" => "model_2.jpg", "imagen" => "model_3.jpg", "imagen" => "model_4.jpg")
    );
           foreach ($models as $model) {

pero no me deja  subir aqui el bloque del codigo EOT , voy ha subir una captura de pantalla...

ya he probado con todas las posible formas de escribir php dentro de EOT....
ejemplo:
{{$model}['name']} , <?php $model['name'] , {$model}['name'] , <?php{$model}['name'] ?>, <?php {{$model}['name']}?>, {$model['name']}

todas ellas sin exito y si de esta forma , consigo con un solo fragmento de codigo html(li), replicar un li tras otro , tantos como variables de resultado , tiene el array, hasta ahi he conseguido llegar pero me daba un error de comillas y estoy probando otras cosas o formas de especificar las variables , que no hay forma de que me las coja....

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
